# How can I show the "descriptionField" on click instead of hover in an amPieChart?

Tags: amcharts

I have looked everywhere.  I currently have a pie chart with desriptionField. However, the description shows when I hover, along with the balloonText. I would love only for the balloon text to show and only after a click should a description show. Like here https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/html-content-in-description-box-of-map-marker/

Except the above demo is for a map and I am using a pie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pie charts don't have a description window like maps. If you want to pop up a div, you can use the [`clickSlice`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#clickSlice) event to generate a popup or modal. You also need to tweak the [`balloonText`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#balloonText) property to remove the `[[description]]` tag from the string (ex: `"balloonText": "[[title]]: [[percents]]% ([[value]])"`). Here's a very basic example using a custom div popup:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "country": "Lithuania",
    "litres": 501.9,
    "description": "This is a test description for Lithuania."
  }, {
    "country": "Czech Republic",
    "litres": 301.9,
    "description": "This is a test description for Czech Republic."
  }, {
    "country": "Ireland",
    "litres": 201.1,
    "description": "This is a test description for Ireland."
  }, {
    "country": "Germany",
    "litres": 165.8,
    "description": "This is a test description for Germany."
  }],
  "valueField": "litres",
  "titleField": "country",
  "balloonText": "[[title]]: [[percents]]% ([[value]])",
  "balloon": {
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "clickSlice",
    "method": function(e) {
      var desc = document.getElementById("description");
      desc.style.top = e.event.pageY + "px";
      desc.style.left = e.event.pageX + "px";
      desc.style.display = "block";
      desc.innerHTML = "<p><strong>" + e.dataItem.title + "</strong><br>Litres: " + e.dataItem.value + "<br>" + e.dataItem.dataContext.description + "</p>";
    }
  }]
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#description {
  position: absolute;
  top: -99999;
  left: -99999;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #000;
  display: none;
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="description"></div>
```

You can add your own close button to this or replace this with a popup/modal implementation from your favorite UI library.